# NodeJs Postgres + AWS Lambda timeout even after successful client connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

**Lambda Function:**

```
const client = new Client({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'rds_host',
    database: 'dbname',
    password: 'db_password',
    port: 5432
});

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
        await client.connect();
        callback(null, "Connected Successfully");
    } catch (e) {
        callback(null, "Error");
    }
};
```

With this code my lambda always get a timeout error, if I get rid of the `cliente.connect()` line, it works fine.

The interesting part is that if I add a `client.query` with `INSERT` the command does work and the row is created at the DB, so why I get a timeout when the `client.connect()` is added and the connection works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that when your handler function is `async`, it's expecting a promise to be resolved, so, instead of using the callback, I would just `return "Connected Successfully";`

[Link to relevant docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html)

There's an example at this link where there's an async handler without the callback.